# Run a function when another function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to run a function when another function is called. `addEventListener` only runs events like "click", "mouseover", etc. However, I'd like to *listen* for a function call.


EXAMPLE:
*Function 1* is called. Afterwards, *Function 2* runs because it saw that *Function 1* was called.


Is there an addEventListener alternative for simple functions and not events? I can't seem to find any.


My goal was to simply run a function everytime a user did something like call for when something was hidden in jQuery or by another JavaScript library or just simply another external JavaScript file with some code I added in.

Comment: @AndrewLi I just do that because a lot of people tend to just read over my questions and answer them incorrectly because they were too lazy to pay attention. If it annoys you that bad, I can change it.

Comment: Please do. It really makes the post seem sloppy and it discourages lots of people from taking the time to actually read it...

Comment: _"I can't just call the second function in the main function because I don't particularly have access to that function"_ Can you provide further details about second function and how that function is accessible or not accessible by first function?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm basically saying the second function would be in an alternate JS file.

Comment: @TyQ. why is that a problem?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you're trying to do with `addEventListener`. The first argument should be a string; the event type

Comment: @Phil Okay,, I thought you could listen for about anything in addEventListener. This is why I tried it, and of course, failed.

Comment: addEventListener is a method of an `event target` - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - in your case, you're trying to add listeners to `window` - but please note what the arguments should be ... a string, a function and an optional boolean

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay, so `addEventListener` can only be used for "click" functions and "mouseover", etc. ?

Comment: no, it can be used for any sort of event, including anything you can think of ... `spanky`, `omfg`, `lol` ...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to simply describe the **actual** problem (preferably with a real, reproducible example)?

Comment: @Phil Already working on it.

Comment: I think his objective here is just to do something every time another function is called. Basically a hacky way to hook into a process of some existing system.

Comment: @l3utterfly No, my goal is to run a function everytime a specific other function is called.

Comment: _"I'm basically saying the second function would be in an alternate JS file."_ What issue are you having accessing and calling function in that file, or calling function which gets content of that file? Requirement is not clear.

Comment: @TyQ. And why would you need to do that? I believe my answer will work for your requirements though.

Comment: @l3butterfly Okay, let me go ahead and test it out.

Comment: _"My goal was to simply run a function everytime a user did something like $("#junior").hide();"_ `.hide()` has a callback function. You can also chain `.promise().then(fn)` where duration of `.hide()` is greater than `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have trigger an event inside `myFunction` and listen to that event.

```js
function myFunction(){
    //This is the main function
    alert('Hello, this is part of the message!');
    // trigger the event
    var event = new CustomEvent("event", { "detail": "Example of an event" });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);



}
// handle here;
document.addEventListener("event", function(){
    //This is the secondary function
    //or the function I need to run after the main function is called
    alert('Hello, this is the other part of the message!');
});
// call main
myFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Simple test!</p>
<p>Long story short, you get message 1, but message 2 never pops up!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! :-) I had to do some editing to get your code to work for my function. In the end, it's basically all the same, but modified to work in my specific situation. This is the end code: `var newEvent = new Event(id + "_closed"); window.dispatchEvent(newEvent);`. I don't know why, but the original code wasn't working because it couldn't be used as a "constructor".

Answer (score 9):

**Introducing a very hacky way**

Since what you are trying to achieve is basically hacking some existing system (you shouldn't run into this problem if you have control over both sides and design your code properly).

It looks like your function is declared globally as well. In that case:
1. store the existing function in a variable
2. overwrite that function with your implementation
3. call the function variable at the start

```
function myFunction(){
    //This is the main function
    alert('Hello, this is part of the message!');
}

var tempfunc = myFunction;

window.myFunction = function() {
    tempfunc();

    // do what you need to do in the event listener here
    alert('Hello, this is the other part of the message!');
}
```

EDIT:

The original question had the requirement that the original function **cannot be modified**, hence my solution. Since they it appears the question has changed.

Comment: I realise sometimes you have business needs which must be met (e.g. wresting with old code), but I DO NOT condone this solution at all. You will run into a lot of un-maintainability and technical-debt.

Comment: Actually this hack is very common and we call it "monkey patch", it is not recommended at all but trust me sometimes this can be the only solution  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an addEventListener alternative for simple functions and not
>   events? I can't seem to find any.
>
> My goal was to simply run a function everytime a user did something
>   like call for when something was hidden in jQuery or by another
>   JavaScript library or just simply another external JavaScript file
>   with some code I added in.

You can use `jQuery.Callbacks()`

```js
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();

function handleCallback1(message) {
  console.log(message, this)
};

function handleCallback2(message) {
  if (this.tagName === "DIV") {
    this.style.color = "green";
  } else {
    this.nextElementSibling.style.color = "blue";
  }
};

$("button, div").on("click", function() {
  callbacks.fireWith(this, ["called from " + this.tagName])
});

callbacks.add(handleCallback1, handleCallback2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>click</button>
<div>click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem in my JavaScript application, and I solved it using `Subject` from **rxjs** library in the following way

```js
var functionCalled$ = new Subject();

functionCalled$.subscribe(fn=>{
    if(fn === 'function1'){
        console.log(fn);
    }
});

function function1(){
    // function's logic ...
    functionCalled$.next('function1');
}

function function2(){
    // function's logic ...
    functionCalled$.next('function2');
}
```

So, I added `functionCalled$.next(/*...*/)` to each function I have and then it is possible to execute additional logic only when specific functions get called